# Ubuntu 12.04 gets very slow after waking up from suspending or sleeping

Tags: 12.04, suspend

Basically after waking up from a time out or from manually suspending, it gets very slow, to the point that it is impossible to even open a terminal on tty1-6.

(edit: I'm referring to Unity or Gnome-Shell)

Could this have anything to do with swap memory?

My fstab is:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=bd4585c8-a303-4ce8-87f1-42737c6e9fd4 /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=36573f57-835f-41a2-ad18-aaa2d397d7d3 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=0bb5194c-2ece-4b4e-8f7e-34aa33bde7d0 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=15854d8c-22d7-4625-b596-5b126232455b none            swap    sw          $
/dev/sda6       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

(I commented line 9 because after installing ubuntu I installed debian in another partition and it apparently changed  sda6 ID, and I was getting a non fatal error on Ubuntu startup. Debian was then removed though, so swap partition is not being shared among operating systems).

Comment: Same issue with Ubuntu 13 / Mint 16. Can't find any solution...

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that this bug is coming from the CPU Governor,
on "ondemand" mode, it was never giving me the full power of my CPU's, only 800Mhz of 2.8Ghz.

So I installed https://launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq and now I can: see why everything is slow and set the CPU frequency I want.

This does not fix the issue (as the Governor does not get smarter) but I do not have to reboot the system anymore.